# Как читать XML из строки?

Tags: c#, xml

XML опытный образец:

```
string xml = @"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
                   <request module='' format='xml'>
                      <filter id='' db='' state='' />
                      <auth id='' />
                    </request>";
```

Чтение xml:

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load(xml); //(вот тут ошибка чтения).
foreach (XmlNode nod in xDoc.SelectNodes("/request/filter"))
{
    foreach (XmlNode node in nod.ChildNodes)
    {
        string id = node.Attributes["id"].Value.ToString();
        string db = node.Attributes["db"].Value.ToString();
        listBox1.Items.Add(string.Format("id={0} db={1}", id, db));
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

> Путь содержит недопустимые знаки

Comment: ф-ция LoadXml (вместо Load) во многих фреймворках.

Comment: Тоже использовал, ошибок нет. Но и информацию не какую не выводит.

Comment: _вот тут ошибка чтения_ - что за ошибка? какой текст ошибки?

Comment: @Grundy - функция Load предполагает имя файла. Ошибка - нет такого `<?xml versio` файла:)

Comment: Какую не такую? Всё хорошо оно грузит. Трассируйте. Проверяйте. Или дополняйте вопрос входными выходными данными.

Comment: Опять же Load ведь читает из потока :), по крайне мере я его использую для чтения входящих потоков.

Comment: @nick_n_a, я сначала не увидел _Путь содержит недопустимые знаки_ , в любом случае текст ошибки автор должен был добавить в вопрос.

Comment: @Macro, чтобы не гадать, что делает Load, и какие параметры он принимает стоит посмотреть документацию и [список перегрузок](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx) - одна перегразка принимает String, и эта перегрузка: _Loads the XML document **from the specified URL**._

Comment: Все разобрался, сам накосячил сильно ))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для загрузки XML из строки используется функция [XmlDocument.LoadXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml(v=vs.110).aspx)